# How can I read build.xml parameters into Jenkins ?

Tags: jenkins

I am having some information in build.xml file which I would like to access in Jenkins email plugin,to be able to send that parameter. How can I access the parameter in Jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the [Inject Env](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin.

Instead of reading the build.xml file, move your properties in a dedicated file (build.properties for example).

Next, this plugin can inject variables in your job using the build.properties file.

Comment: Thanks. I can see the message getting printed on the jenkins console, so if I directly store it in Jenkins env variables would that help. I don't want to write the values to a new properties file

Comment: Yep you can directly set your variables with the Inject env plugin. Please vote for my solution if it helped :)